# I don't want to add the new row when I clicked a checkbox with DataGridView.(C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to use dataGridView(with C#), and I have a question.

[image]

This is my dataGridView.

If i click on the checkbox, which is shown in red squares, a new row is automatically added. Why is this?

In the code, I have never added any event when I clicked the checkbox.

code)
namespace TestWinForm
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
List saved_file_names = new List();
int table_index = 0;

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Title = "열기";
            ofd.Filter = "txt파일 | *.txt";
            ofd.Multiselect = true; //  파일 다중 선택

            DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();

            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                foreach (string file_name in ofd.FileNames)
                {
                    //  1. 중복체크
                    if (saved_file_names.Contains(file_name))
                        continue;

                    //  2. 중복되지않은 파일들을 추가.
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[table_index].Cells[1].Value = table_index + 1;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[table_index].Cells[2].Value = file_name;
                    saved_file_names.Add(file_name);
                    dataGridView1.Rows[table_index].Cells[3].Value = "none";
                    table_index++;
                }
            }
        }

        private void delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool is_checked = false;
            List<int> delete_index = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < table_index; i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value) == true)
                    delete_index.Add(i);
            }

            if (delete_index.Count == 0)
                return;

            delete_index.Reverse();

            foreach (var index in delete_index)
            {
                table_index--;
                saved_file_names.RemoveAt(index);
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(index);
            }


        }

        private void decode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex == -1)
            {
                e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, false);
                Point pt = e.CellBounds.Location;

                int nChkBoxWidth = 15;
                int nChkBoxHeight = 15;
                int offsetx = (e.CellBounds.Width - nChkBoxWidth) / 2;
                int offsety = (e.CellBounds.Height - nChkBoxHeight) / 2;

                pt.X += offsetx;
                pt.Y += offsety;

                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();

                cb.Size = new Size(nChkBoxWidth, nChkBoxHeight);
                cb.Location = pt;
                cb.Checked = true;
                cb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(dgvCheckBox_CheckedChanged);

                ((DataGridView)sender).Controls.Add(cb);

                e.Handled = true;

            }

        }

        private void dgvCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                r.Cells[0].Value = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It will be a great help if you show us your code.

Comment: Try by setting AllowUserToAddRows to false

Comment: @McNets thank you, Please forgive me for not thanking earlier.  I thought I left a comment.